# Is querying an inclusive range more efficient than a discrete set of values?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a property, A, in my documents that hold a range of integers from 1 to 10.

It is indexed.

Considering these 2 queries:

```
Find all documents where `A` is between 2 and 7.
```

vs

```
Find all documents where A == 2, A == 9, A == 4, A == 7
```

Would there be an performance difference between the 2 queries? If so which is faster, and why?

Comment: have you tried looking at execution stats usin explain()

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/qIrza1wCC4D  https://mongoplayground.net/p/6lZrL3jdeBG

Comment: thx. I can see that they both use the index scan as expected. But the `operationTime` field is basically the same

Comment: maybe the queris are too simple

Comment: I increased the `count` field to 100000000

Comment: the mongoplayground max is 100/collection so it wont go beyond 100 even if you do 1million

Comment: Wouldn't the number of comparisons be the most significant factor?  E.g., _"`A` is between 2 and 7"_ has 2 comparisons, whereas _"A == 2, A == 9, A == 4, A == 7"_ has 4 comparisons.  OFC, if the projection allows a _covered_ query, that would significantly affect the overall query time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

Since MongoDB uses flexible schemas, even though you note that your documents only contain integers in the 'A' field, it is valid from the database viewpoint to store a document like `{ A: 3.14 }`.  Such a document would be found by the first query you show, but not the second.

The query to find multiple discreet values will use a separate index scan for each value, while the query to find the range will use a single index scan from the start of the range to the end.

Whether or not this difference would impact performance depends on how many documents there are in each of the ranges.

Comment: Well then in theory, the range scanner will be faster as it only requires one index scan, while the the discreet scanner requires multiple index scans?

Comment: In my experience, MongoDB index scan performance depends much more on the number of keys scanned than the number of ranges.

Comment: Are separate index scans performed in parallel via threads?

Comment: I don't think they are, but (scanning from A to B, skipping to C and then scanning to D) vs (scanning from A to D) would reasonably perform similarly on single threads.